# Running code when the runloop is idle

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, uikit

I'm looking for a behaviour similar to

```
[[NSNotificationQueue defaultQueue] enqueueNotification:not postingStyle:NSPostWhenIdle coalesceMask:NSNotificationCoalescingOnName|NSNotificationCoalescingOnSender forModes:nil];
```

but without using notifications, somehow enqueue a selector or block instead of a notification.

As for my motives (just to see if this is a legitimate way of doing it). I add multiple subviews to a view, obviously there's no way one can know how many, so each time I add a subview I have to perform some calculations by invoking `layoutIfNeeded` to layout the subviews in a specific manner. Now, I was thinking, if I would be able to invoke the method only when the runloop becomes idle (somehow postpone the invocation and coalesce it), then all the subviews would have been already added by the time it performs the layout calculations. Hope it makes sense.

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
[super layoutSubviews];


UIView* prevView = nil;
for (NSUInteger i=0; i<[self.subviews count]; i++) {
    UIView* view = self.subviews[i];
    CGFloat spacing = prevView!=nil?self.spacing:0;
    view.topLeft = CGPointOffset(prevView.bottomLeft, spacing, 0);
    prevView = view;
}

[self fitSubviews];
}
```

Added the code I have in my `layoutSubview` method.

Comment: There must be a simpler way of solving this, like overriding  `layoutSubviews` to test a global flag (`defer_layout`) and starting a timer on first invocation.  Then when the timer fires, clear the `defer_layout` flag and actually do the laying out. Well something like that; needs some finesse but looks more achievable than the direction you are heading.

Comment: `setNeedsLayout` already defers and coalesces — is that insufficient?

Comment: interesting that you pointed that out @Tommy. Because it really does, however, when I use it instead of `layoutIfNeeded`, I can't change the view size in `layoutSubviews`, I mean is not entering a infinite loop as I originally though since probably `setSize:` calls `layoutIfNeeded`, but it simply doesn't change the size (always 0)

Comment: @trojanfoe that's certainly not simpler :)

Comment: So what you sort of want to do is a combination of `sizeThatFits:` (as you're not meant to override `sizeToFit` directly) and `layoutSubviews`, presumably because they both end up doing pretty much the same calculations so it feels neater to do the work only once?

Comment: you should just use `-setNeedsLayout` and then `-layoutSubviews`. As @Tommy points out, -setNeedsLayout calls are already coalesced... -layoutSubviews will be called at most once per render loop. Also, unless your layout is taking lots of CPU, this is an optimization you don't need to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the general question, the easiest solution would be something like:

```
- (void)setNeedsCustomTask
{
    // cancel any previously scheduled call to perform the task
    [NSObject
         cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self
         selector:@selector(doCustomTask)
         object:nil];

    // schedule a new call; because you've specified any delay
    // at all this will be scheduled to occur in the future rather than
    // right now and because you've specified a 0.0 delay it'll be
    // as soon as possible in the future
    [self performSelector:@selector(doCustomTask) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
}

- (void)doCustomTask
{
    NSLog(@"I am a custom task");
}
```

That works because `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` schedules the call on the runloop in the future. You can also specify `inModes:` e.g. if you wanted to avoid tracking mode.

There's obviously some technical inefficiency in cancelling and rescheduling rather than keeping a flag handy but it's neat because you don't explicitly need to marshall state. So I think there'd be a good premature optimisation argument for just doing this first.

Comment: That's a neat trick @Tommy. Thanks for sharing. It solves my original problem, and will keep it in mind for future use. At the moment I found a way to align my subviews using only `setNeedsLayout` and `layoutSubviews` which already defers and coalesces as you mentioned in one of you comments above.